# Integrate Visual Studio Code with Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-code, tfs

We are trying to integrate Visual Studio Code with Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. Our Visual Studio Code version is 1.87.0

We installed TFS extension as suggested [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=generalov.vscode-tfs)

Then we setup the TF path

[image]

Then we tried Alt+T -> Add files and folders to version control. At that time we faced following issue

[image]

We tried tf workspace and gor error as below
[Screen shot from VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPsiV.png)

We added env variable also
[Screen shot Env variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qj43.png)

how do we need to fix this?

Comment: pretty sure you just need to switch your double backslashes to single ones. the docs you're following are probably written for pasting into JSON, in the case of editing settings.json. But if you're using the settings UI, then you don't need to escape backslashes because the settings editor will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

Since you have installed VS, you may consider to [Develop and share code in TFVC with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs?view=tfs-2018) instead of VSCode.

As for the error that`tf command is not recognized` in normal PowerShell prompt, we can add the path to `tf.exe` into the `Path` environment variable.

[image]

We can then open a new PowerShell session or reopen VSCode -> Test to run `tf workspaces` command in the terminal session and see if `tf` command can work.

[image]

---

Before using the `TFS` VSCode extension, you need to create a local workspace mapping with the remote TFVC repo in Azure DevOps Server.

For this, you can run `tf workspace /new` commands in Developer PowerShell of Visual Studio. See [Workspace command (Team Foundation Version Control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspace-command?view=tfs-2018) for more details.

```
tf workspace /new TFVCProject-LocalWorkspace /comment:"Local workspace for TFVCProject" /collection:http://aztfs2022/DefaultCollection/
```

[image]

[image]

Then you may open your local workspace folder in VSCode -> Press `Alt+T` -> Select a file to `Check Out for Edit`;

[image]

What worth mentioning is that this extension doesn't seem to enable `check-in` function in the shortcut menu. See this open issue [no check-in · Issue #7 · generalov/vscode-tfs · GitHub](https://github.com/generalov/vscode-tfs/issues/7). You may reach out to the extension author/maintainer for confirmation.

The workaround is to run `tf checkin` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/checkin-command?view=tfs-2018). I expose the path of `tf.exe` into environment variables `PATH` to run `tf` commands directly in VSCode `Terminal` session
[image]

Please be advised to **BACKUP your current pending changes** before testing the workflow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We are using TFS 2018

Comment: My instance is Azure DevOps Server 2022 and I afraid I am unable to setup TFS2018 for a test at the moment. However, the `tf` command does support TFS2018. I have updated the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspace-command?view=tfs-2018) for reference. Did you encounter any issue following my workflow?

Comment: We have this http://sr-tfs2018:8080/tfs/xxxx/ TFS path already. I used to connect to that  after connecting to VPN and will be placing my files manually. Now I planned to integrate with VS code. How can I map that. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspace-command?view=tfs-2018)? This VSCode extension simply makes `tf` commands friendly via VSCode UI. What do you mean by TFS path by the way? What command have you tried to ensure the `tf.exe` tool get to know which remote TFVC repo to map with? Please share your detailed scenario in the original post, so that we can assist further.

Comment: Went through the document and tried tf command. Still have issues. Also shared the detailed scenario to original post. Could you please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @PHPTeam, Thanks for taking time to share the update. I can see you were unable to run the `tf` command as your environment variable was not set correctly. Please check my update in the answer and see if you can use `tf` command and then let us know if there is any local workspace that are already created and mapped with your TFS collection. Please **don't** share any sensitive information (ip/token/password/certificate, etc.) in the post, as it is publicly visible.

Comment: And by the way, since you have installed VS, would you consider to [Develop and share code in TFVC with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs?view=tfs-2018) instead of VSCode?

Comment: Hi Alvin, Thank you for your reply. In our organization PHP team is using Visual Studio Code (with php code sniffer and Xdebug extensions). So we are checking this. We setup the env variables as suggested. But still facing same issue. When try the ‘tf’ command from command prompt after navigating to ‘\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\’ folder the command is working. From VS Code -> Terminal we are facing same issue. We are checking with our system support.

Comment: Hi @PHPTeam, Good day to you. How is the issue going. May I know if it could be resolved with the creation of local workspace mapping with the tfs repo by running the `tf` commands? Thanks for the time and efforts which may help the community members. Happy weekends.

Comment: Hi Alvin, In our organization they asked to check using Visual Studio. So I will use your above references and check. I will get back in case if queries. Thanks

Comment: Hi Alvin, We have planned to use Visual Studio as IDE for our PHP web application. Please suggest how to set up PHP_code sniffer and Xdebug in Visual Studio. Or do we have alternate tools. Can you please help. Thanks

Comment: Hi @PHPTeam, Good day. I would like to help further. But to be honest, I am not so familiar with your follow-up query, as you are reaching out to the subcommunity of `Azure DevOps` rather than `PHP`. I would suggest creating a new thread for the specific question with the tags of `PHP` and `Visual Studio`. Regarding our original issue under discussion, I suppose it is resolved as you opt to use VS as suggested. Thanks for the time and update here to benefit other users. Cheers!